# Make text and drop down list inline together bootstrap

Tags: html

[The text and drop down are not neat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtHA6.png)i am trying to have a text and drop down list together in the same row. However, when i add the drop down list the text position's changes and it looks weird. Someone help me please.

```html
 <div class="row">
      Sort By: 
<select    name="services" class=' col-md-4 form-control' id="services" >
<option value ="none">Nothing</option>
<option value ="guava">Guava</option>
<option value ="lychee">Lychee</option>
<option value ="papaya">Papaya</option>
</select>
   </div>
```

Comment: need more detail ?

Comment: If you want to affect how elements are styled you should look into CSS. Also, you should edit your question to include the outcome you are trying to accomplish. Saying it "looks weird" isn't enough to go off. How should it look?

Answer (score 0):

You can use select multiple for this, if you don't want to allow multiple select you can make a js fix to select only 1 option

```css
#services
{
  width: 220px;
  height: 24px;
}
#services option
{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
      Sort By: 
<select  multiple  name="services" class=' col-md-4 form-control' id="services" >
<option value ="none">Nothing</option>
<option value ="guava">Guava</option>
<option value ="lychee">Lychee</option>
<option value ="papaya">Papaya</option>
</select>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably referring to the fact that they are not correctly vertically aligned. This can be easily solved by ensuring you have for both the list and the label: 
`vertical-align: (middle or top)` depending on your need.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is just bootstrap's `my-auto` class to do vertical alignment.
Try this:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-auto my-auto">
      Sort By:
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <select name="services"
              class='form-control'
              id="services">
        <option value="none">Nothing</option>
        <option value="guava">Guava</option>
        <option value="lychee">Lychee</option>
        <option value="papaya">Papaya</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S. Also while using bootstrap always put your content inside `col`-s instead of `row`-s. as [documetnation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) says:

> In a grid layout, content must be placed within columns and only
>   columns may be immediate children of rows.